# How do I check if an array contains particular index in Pascal?

Tags: arrays, pascal

E.g. I have this array:

```
type
    OptionRange = array[ 1..9 ] of integer;
```

How do I check if array[x] exists?

Actually, I want to limit user input with the array index. Am I doing the wrong thing? Is there a better practical solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Free Pascal and the Borland dialects (and perhaps elsewhere as well), you can use the `Low` and `High` functions on the array type or a variable of the array type. I see this used most often to determine the bounds for `for` loops:

```
var
  range: OptionRange;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(range) to High(range) do begin
    range[i] := GetOptionRangeElement(i);
  end;
end;
```

You can also define a *subrange type* and then use it to define both the array and the index variables you use on the array:

```
type
  OptionRangeIndex = 1..9;
  OptionRange = array[OptionRangeIndex] of Integer;
var
  range: OptionRange;
  i: OptionRangeIndex;
```

Then, when you have range checking enabled (assuming your compiler offers such a feature) and you use a value that's outside the range for `OptionRange` indices, you'll get a run-time error that you can catch and handle however you want.

I'm not really sure what an *option range* is or why an array of nine integers would be used to represent one, but I figure that's a name-selection issue.